# Get ratio between the length of a table and one of its subsets via SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named `A` that contains a column named `x`. What I'm trying to do is to count the number of items that belong to a certain subset of A (more precisely, the ones that satisfy the `x > 4` condition) via a single SELECT query, for example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM A
WHERE x > 4;
```

From thereon, I'd like to calculate the ratio between the size of this particular subset of `A` and `A` as a whole, i.e. perform the following division:

```
size_subset / size_A
```

My question is - how would I combine all of these pieces into a single SQL SELECT query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My server is down, not able to get sure of the answer below:

```
SELECT count(case when x > 4 then x else null end) / COUNT(*) FROM A;
```

Is a slight better because its just a count, not a sum (nulls ill not be accounted)

but i prefer to do:

```
select (SELECT count(*) FROM A where x > 4)/(SELECT count(*) FROM A);
```

As I guess it can do faster

Answer (score 0):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT sum(case when x > 4 then 1 else 0 end) / COUNT(*)
FROM A;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a less clunky way of doing this, but:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN x > 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) FROM A
```